# Nested Loop is giving me same or wrong answers when i need to calculate the equity return

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, nested

**Background**: Greetings! I had to randomly sample a value from normal distribution (done) and use that value (mean is "that value") to see how much an initial equity value of 100 increases in 3582weeks and provide the final profited value. As in:

equity=100

equity = equity + 100*mean

I need to run 1000 trials to see how different values of "mean" give different profited values.

I'm able to get the answer for the 3582 weeks for the first trial, but when i'm adding another loop for "1000 trials," it's either giving me the same values or wrong values.

**Problem**: The loop is either giving me the same values or completely in-correct values. method: computeStats(){..}

***Note***: I've shown the constructor in the blog just for reference to show what i'm really doing.

```
class Sample extends SimulateMarket{ //SimulateMarket is the Application class

ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();
private double mean, stdDev; 
private Random random;
SimulateMarket mySim = new SimulateMarket(); //mySim is an instance of SimulateMarket class used to access variables of Simulate Class

public Sample(int size, double theMean, double theStdDev){ //Comstructor used for the Distributional Technique
    random = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<3582 ; i++)
        data.add(theMean+random.nextGaussian()*theStdDev); //Random sampling from Normal Distribution 
    mean = getMean(); //getMean() method is used to get Mean 
    stdDev = getStdDev(mean);
    Collections.sort(data);//getStdDev is used for getting Standard Deviation
    System.out.println(this); //for printing the results
}

public void computeStats(){
    ArrayList<Double> myData = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
        equity = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<3582; i++){ 
        equity = equity + 100*mean;

    }
    myData.add(equity);
    }

    for(Double num: myData){
        System.out.println(num);
    }


}
```

Comment: It looks like you're computing the same stats 1000 times. Do you want to compute 1000 different samples? You don't need your 1000 loop in `computeStats` for that. You need it wherever you're creating your `new Sample()`.

Comment: that worked! Apparently i was stuck in this thing since 5 hours!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, i was adding the 1000 loop in the wrong place. That's where it needs to be- in the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
for(int j=0; j<1000; j++){
    Sample equity = new Sample(3582, 0.0016, 0.0205);
    equity.computeStats();
    }
}
```